# Problema al crear el producto final con Bootstrap-Vue

Tags: web, vue.js, build, bootstrap-vue

Estoy haciendo la web para un evento y tengo problemas a la hora de subir la versión al servidor. Funciona perfectamente en la versión de desarrollo, pero por alguna razón que se me pasa no se compone como debería, únicamente se ve el footer. He creado el producto utilizando `vue init bootstrap-vue/webpack my-project`. Para componerla estoy utilizando `vue-build prod`.

He probado usando el ejemplo que viene al iniciar el proyecto pero tampoco funciona su versión de producción. Probablemente se me olvida añadir algo, pero después de consultar la documentación soy incapaz de verlo.

El código se encuentra en: https://github.com/MGijon/Citython/tree/master/web

Answer (score 0):

Suena a como si algun complemento, js o css no se cargara, prueba en el navegador, la version del servidor, presionando F12 en Firefox o Chrome y verifica en la consola que te dice o en red si hay algo faltante.
Puede que lo hayas incluido en el servidor y referenciado mal en la ruta. No siempre es lo mismo local que en un servidor.

Comment: Parece que no está cargando un archivo concreto css, pero lo he subido al servidor, no sé cómo arreglarlo.
http://thegraph.es/dist2b/

Comment: a veces el servidor tarda en ponerlo disponible. Prueba copiar la URL completa del css y pegarla en otra pestaña a ver si carga

Comment: El archivo aparece en la pestaña de recursos del inspector pero no se encuentra accesible por url.
Sin embargo si parece que está en el servidor si lo compruebo desde mi acceso http.

Comment: Si no se puede acceder por url algo está mal